# JxBrowser - use on server, what is required?

Tags: jxbrowser

How do you use JXBrowser on a server? It can't run in no headless mode.

I've tried install xorg and run xorg on the server, then ssh -X ... from terminal.

It seems to pass, but output not the same as on laptop.

Also tried to install tightvnc-server, the same.

Also tried with xvfb, the same.

**I am running on ubuntu 16.10, could that be the reason?**

Comment: JxBrowser doesn't support headless environment. If you run JxBrowser on Linux server without GUI, then please make sure that your run X server. In general, the idea is the following: JxBrowser works in the same environment where Google Chrome works without any issues.

Comment: @Vladimir So it won't work using -X or xvfb? Do I need to install for instance tightvnc and log in to the graphical component to get it to run? I should mention that it appears as if it is running, it passes the validation level and I can execute scripts, however nothing is returned back.

Comment: I'm not familiar with headless linux configuration, but I know that JxBrowser won't work without running X Server in a headless linux environment, because Chromium engine doesn't support it. If you see that the library is running and executes scripts, then it means that the library works. If you see that the library doesn't work in the way you expect it to work, then it's another issue that's not related to this StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, it turned to be due to something else depending on production environment setup.

Comment: So... now that Chrome does support headless mode, JxBrowser should support it too?